# Is it possible to pipe Xamarin output into less on Mac?

Tags: c#, xamarin, terminal, xamarin-studio, less-unix

I'm running C# scripts from Xamarin on my MacbookPro and it opens Console Apps in the Terminal. My output is huge and I'm wondering if I can pipe the output from Xamarin into `less` so I can use `less` as a pager.

Or, is there maybe a way to execute a C# file/project from a directory using shell?

Comment: if it's just a console app, you can execute it with the mono cmd line

Comment: @Jason - ah thanks, that worked!

Comment: would accept this as answer @Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can execute it with the mono cmd line tool